# GPT or MBR: How do I know?

Tags: hard-disk, gpt, mbr

How can I tell whether my harddrive is laid out using an [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) or [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) format?

Comment: [Same question on AU](http://askubuntu.com/questions/387351/how-can-i-detect-whether-my-disk-is-using-gpt-or-mbr-from-a-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lsblk` from `util-linux` [v. 2.33 and later](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.33/v2.33-rc1-ChangeLog), one can print only the partition table type via

```
lsblk /dev/nvme0n1 -dno pttype
```

```
gpt
```

`d` omits children/slaves, `n` omits headers and `o` prints only the specified field.
It's quite handy since it doesn't need post-processing the output and doesn't require root access.

Comment: For an MBR formatted device this reports `dos` instead.

Comment: @goldilocks - afaik the concept of `mbr` was first introduced with IBM PC-DOS 2.0 and most likely that's why almost all disk management tools call this type of partition table `dos` (rarely `msdos`) instead of `mbr` (the only exception being `gdisk` which is a fairly new app)

Comment: o_O I know.  Just indicating it for posterity.  I think "DOS MBR" is/was used often as well, but that fact that there aren't any other widespread flavours of mbr led to one or the other being sufficient.

Answer (score 141):

You can use `parted -l` to determine the type of partition table. Eg:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA THNSNS25 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  32.2GB  32.2GB  primary  ext4         boot
 2      32.2GB  256GB   224GB   primary  ext4


Model: ATA Hitachi HDT72101 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  32.2GB  32.2GB  primary  ext4            boot
 2      32.2GB  996GB   964GB   primary  ext4
 3      996GB   1000GB  4295MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

The `Partition Table` field shows that I am using a `msdos` MBR partition table (the one still commonly used for Linux and Windows) on both disks. From the `man` page `parted` can create (and thus hopefully identify) the following types of partition table (or more broadly `disk label'):

```
bsd
dvh
gpt    - this is a GPT partition table
loop   - this is raw disk access without a partition table
mac
msdos  - this is a standard MBR partition table
pc98
sun
```

#### Update

It is worth adding the command for listing a single partition since this is not obvious without some knowledge of `parted` and it can be a pain finding the data you need if there are multiple drives. For `/dev/sda` you would do:

```
parted /dev/sda print
```

Comment: That is a great command, Graeme. Although I've been using Linux for several years, I had never really noticed it. Thanks!

Comment: `parted /dev/sda p` will do, too.

Comment: i had to do "sudo parted -l"

Answer (score 47):

On linux, you can check this via the `gdisk` tool which should be available for any distro.

```
gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

Here, `/dev/sda` is the device node *of the physical drive*, not a partition (`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, etc. are partitions).

If you see something that includes:

```
***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************
```

You have a MBR style disk.  Don't worry, this did not do any harm.

If you don't see this warning, you have a GPT disk, or a *[hybrid GPT/MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html)* disk.  The later are used mostly on Apple machines intended to dual-boot versions of MS Windows which do not support GPT.  `gdisk` will indicate this with:

```
Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT
```

They may also be used in other situations where support for both styles is required.

Comment: Or the reverse - trying  to use `cfdisk` on a GPT partition will also result in a warning.

Comment: If not installed and not in a `gdisk` package, it can be found in the `gptfdisk` package... at least on Gentoo.

Comment: @orion I would not recommend that as some versions of tools like `fdisk` or `cfdisk` may support GPT and therefore not show an error.

Comment: For me `gdisk` detects a hybrid GPT+MBR partition table and gives `Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.`. This seems to be the only method which will detect a hybrid table.

Comment: @Graeme : Thanks.  I was unaware of these (the original hybrid reference was edited in by Stephane Chazelas), but I did a bit of reading and added some details.

Answer (score 20):

As the OS was not specified, here is **FreeBSD** way of doing things.

All is done through the `gpart` command (short for GEOM partioner - nothing to do with GNU).

A simple `gpart show` would show you all the available partitions of all the disks, but you can specify the device to have a more precise look on one:

- legacy partition layout with *MBR* (aka "msdos") and *BSD* partition schemes (a 2-level partitioning was usually required for BSD systems, unless using the full disk):

  `$`**`gpart show`**

  ```
  =>      63  67108801  ada0  MBR  (32G)
          63  67108545     1  freebsd  [active]  (32G)
    67108608       256        - free -  (128k)

  =>       0  67108545  ada0s1  BSD  (32G)
           0   2097152       2  freebsd-swap  (1.0G)
     2097152  65011393       1  freebsd-ufs  (31G)
  ```
- modern partition layout using *GPT*:

  `$`**`gpart show /dev/ada2`**

  ```
  =>       34  976773101  ada2  GPT  (465G)
           34          6        - free -  (3.0k)
           40        128     1  freebsd-boot  (64k)
          168   67108864     2  freebsd-swap  (32G)
     67109032  901775360     3  freebsd-zfs  (430G)
  ```

To know more, all is in the [`gpart` manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gpart&sektion=8).

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
$ sudo fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x987c1a05


Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 250068991 249067522 118.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 250068991 249067520 118.8G 8e Linux LVM
```

See the **Disklabel type: dos**. If it shows dos that means it is MBR schema else GPT schema

Answer (score 10):

With `udisks` on Linux:

```
$ sudo /lib/udev/udisks-part-id /dev/sda
using device_file=/dev/sda syspath=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda, offset=0 ao=0 and number=0 for /dev/sda
Entering MS-DOS parser (offset=0, size=500107862016)
MSDOS_MAGIC found
found partition type 0xee => protective MBR for GPT
Exiting MS-DOS parser
Entering EFI GPT parser
GPT magic found
partition_entry_lba=2
num_entries=128
size_of_entry=128
Leaving EFI GPT parser
EFI GPT partition table detected
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE=1
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME=gpt
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_COUNT=4
```

Above, I've got a drive with hybrid GPT+MS-DOS partitioning. In that case, the Linux kernel ignores the MS-DOS partitioning, which is why `udisks` sets UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME to gpt.

That udisks-part-id tool is used to populate the udev database. So if you've got `udisks` installed, you should be able to query that information even as a non-priviledged user with:

```
$ udevadm info -q property -n sda | grep UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME
UDISKS_PARTITION_TABLE_SCHEME=gpt
```

Comment: Note that you will get similar output regardless of whether there is a hybrid GPT+MBR or not. GPT requires a fake MBR with a single full disk partition of type `0xee`. In a hybrid this is a normal MBR with one `0xee` partition (and potential for major problems if the MBR data goes out of sync with the GPT data).

Comment: On one of the CentOS systems where I tried this, it prints ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos, so grep fails to find the line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `blkid`. But you may need to run it as root or as `sudo blkid`.

Examples with output:

```
# blkid /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: PTUUID="92f03b9b-7402-4ad2-8316-08a991c237b3" PTTYPE="gpt"

# blkid -o export /dev/sdc
DEVNAME=/dev/sdc
PTUUID=92f03b9b-7402-4ad2-8316-08a991c237b3
PTTYPE=gpt
```

Or in a script, with the `-o value` option :

```
disk=$1
part_type=$(blkid -o value -s PTTYPE $disk)
case $part_type in
    gpt)  echo "GPT";;
    dos)  echo "MBR";;
    *)    echo "partition is $part_type";;
esac
```

---

Alternatively as a `$USER` you could check for the existence of an EFI Partition (which would indicate a `gpt` partition scheme):

```
$ lsblk | grep -i efi

├─nvme0n1p1      259:2    0   100M  0 part  /boot/efi
```

Comment: Which blkid version is this? When I try with 2.17.0, it doesn't print anything for the whole disk, it only shows information for individual partitions.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov : Indeed, version 2.27 in Ubuntu 16 doesn't show it. Version 2.33.1 in Debian 10 does show it.

Answer (score 3):

In my [Alpine Linux Partition scripts](http://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/alpine-linux/25-alpine-linux-luks-encrypted-installations) I use:

```
check_scheme() {
    fdisk -l $1 |grep "Disklabel type:" |awk '{ print $3 }'
}
```

Comment: On my *Ubuntu 18.04* system `fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep -i disklabel` returns nothing, (*GNU Fdisk 1.3.0a*).

Comment: should be `Disklabel`, not lowercase `disklabel`, maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with fdisk and awk

```bsh
fdisk -l | awk '/Disklabel type:/ {print $3}'
```